# socket read get all data before return

Tags: c, sockets, message-queue

I am writing a tcp proxy, which maintains a message queue. I need to pop out the front msg from the queue once get response from server. The problem is that the size of my server response msg is large, the read function will return before all datas are collected. How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: A couple of ideas are 1) pass the size of the data before the data itself and read until that many bytes are read, or 2) Have something that marks the end of the message at the end of it.

Comment: Why the queue? Proxy servers don't have queues. For the most part they just read and write bytes.

Comment: Is there any need to deal with this problem?  What will go wrong if you just send() the bytes you've recv'd, as you receive them?

Comment: @itsme86 message length is not fixed and not known, I think it's better to loop until not message comes anymore like others said

Comment: @EJP yeah I cannot because each of my message is an entity,and I have multiple clients, that's why I need a message queue :P

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I have multiple clients . When all of them sends messages to the same server, I need a queue. What my logic is when message for the queue head reaches , pop it out of the queue. And if message is large, the read() will not wait for all bytes for that certain client reach and return earlier, the queue head client didn't get enough bytes it wants

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code snippets to know the data structures involved, it sounds like you just need to loop through your socket read() calls until you've read enough data to satisfy the constraints on a "full message." Once you've got a full message, you can put that on your queue and pop off the first one, or just return that if it is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, you need a loop like this:

```
size_t read_buffer(int sockfd, char *buffer, size_t reqlen)
{
    char   *cur_buffer = buffer;
    size_t  bytes_left = reqlen;
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    while ((bytes_read = read(sockfd, cur_buffer, bytes_left)) > 0)
    {
        cur_buffer += bytes_read;
        bytes_left -= bytes_read;
    }
    return(cur_buffer - buffer);
}
```

You can decide what to do on a read error — whether to return the number of bytes read or an error indication (probably `-1`).  The code returns the number of bytes read; if it wasn't the requested length, it is reasonable to suppose that the missing bytes will never be forthcoming (so probably you'll end up ignoring what was read in the calling code).  You might want to recognize `bytes_read == -1 && errno == EINTR` (the read was interrupted) and try to read again.

<sup>Warning: uncompiled, much less tested, code!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think you need to queue messages, assemble complete responses, etc., and you haven't answered the comments that were posted asking about that, but once the initial handshake completes, all a normal proxy server has to do is copy bytes in both directions simultaneously, as they arrive, without bothing about messages at all:

```
while ((count = recv(insocket, buffer, 0, sizeof buffer, 0)) > 0)
{
    send(outsocket, buffer, 0, count, 0);
}
```

You need two threads, one doing this in each direction, per connection. When both threads have exited these loops, close both sockets.